# leetcode 24 Swap Nodes in Pairs. An unexpected and buggy error! (Error - Found cycle in the ListNode) use the language Java

Tags: java, linked-list

When I practice LinkedList. I made a really unexpected error `Error - Found cycle in the ListNode`. I try to search through the internet but no satisfying result and exam my code almost 5 times. Sadly, I failed. I'm learning code by myself so I can find almost no guys to help me in reality. I will be really appreciated if you can help me!
This is the leetcode URL: https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/
I guess there is something wrong in the second for loops. My code is as follows:

```java
class Solution {
  public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {
    // get the length of head
    ListNode q = head;
    int length = 0;
    while (q != null) {
      length++;
      q = q.next;
    }
    // make a dumHead
    ListNode dumHead = new ListNode(0);
    q = dumHead;

    //use loops for length/2 times and each time swap two ListNode
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
      ListNode mid = head;
      head = head.next;
      q.next = head;
      head = head.next;
      q = q.next;
      q.next = mid;
      q = q.next;
    }
    // if there is still a single ListNode, just add it!
    if (head != null) {
      q.next = head;
    }
    return dumHead.next;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much easier to solve the problem recursively:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final ListNode swapPairs(
        final ListNode head
    ) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        final ListNode swappedHead = head.next;
        head.next = swapPairs(head.next.next);
        swappedHead.next = head;
        return swappedHead;
    }
}
```

Here is LeetCode's iterative solution (with comments) using a [Sentinel Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) similar to yours:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {

        // Dummy node acts as the prevNode for the head node
        // of the list and hence stores pointer to the head node.
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
        dummy.next = head;

        ListNode prevNode = dummy;

        while ((head != null) && (head.next != null)) {

            // Nodes to be swapped
            ListNode firstNode = head;
            ListNode secondNode = head.next;

            // Swapping
            prevNode.next = secondNode;
            firstNode.next = secondNode.next;
            secondNode.next = firstNode;

            // Reinitializing the head and prevNode for next swap
            prevNode = firstNode;
            head = firstNode.next; // jump
        }

        // Return the new head node.
        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```